# How to get Instant.now with time as zero?

Tags: java

The `Instant.now();` gives `2022-12-14T22:55:56.055612600Z`. But I would like to have output like this `2022-12-14T00:00:00.000Z`. Meaning, I need instant to provide me with current date, but the time with all zeros. How can I achieve?

Comment: the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) shows all methods of the `Instant` class - e.g. `truncatedTo()` (with `ChronoUnit.DAYS)`)

Comment: It's worth being *very* aware that "current date" is only with respect to UTC in this case. That may be what you want, but you should check.